# Migração oracle para sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Alguém pode me indicar um boa ferramenta de migração de dados para do banco de dados oracle para o banco de dados sql server e vice-versa?
 Preciso pegar muito registros do banco de dados oracle e salvar no banco sql server, preciso que a migração seja feita em período de tempos também, exemplo:
A cada  20 minutos levar uma quantidade x de dados do oracle para o sql server.
 Se alguém souber e puder deixar a documentação também vai me ajudar muito.

Comment: Tente fazer a sua pergunta neste site https://serverfault.com

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017 Ferramenta da importação da Microsoft... segue documentação, ali tem os links para download tbm

Comment: @Tacila Me parece que o que solicita não é migração mas sim sincronização ou replicação de bases de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Para a migração você pode utilizar o Assistente de Migração (SSMA) para Oracle, cuja documentação está disponível em [Introdução ao SSMA para Oracle](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssma/oracle/getting-started-with-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql).

Para o processo de sincronizar periodicamente a base de dados do SQL Server com dados oriundos do Oracle Database, uma opção é a vinculação de servidores. Vide [Criar servidores vinculados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine).

Também existe a opção de utilizar a replicação transacional através de publicadores Oracle; vide [Oracle Publishing Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/oracle-publishing-overview). Mas esta é bem mais complexa...

Comment: Muito obrigada meu amigo!